# I need help with $\int \frac{4-8x^2}{\sqrt[3]{2x^3-2x+1}} \, dx$

Tags: integration

I need help  with:
$$\int \frac{4-8x^2}{\sqrt[3]{2x^3-2x+1}} \, dx$$
So far I tried a couple of substitutions and factorization, but nothing is working.

On the numerator I tried:
$$4\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$
And on the denominator I tried to make some derivatives for substitution.
$$3\left(6x^2-2\right)dx$$
And
$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt{2x^3-2x+1}\right)\left(6x^2-2\right)$$

Comment: Welcome. Your integral is not calculable by elementary means.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any suggestion or any other methods I could try?

Comment: Here's the first thing I think of $$ \begin{align}
u & = \sqrt[3]{ 2x^3-2x+1 } \\ {} \\
u^3 & = 2x^3 - 2x + 1 \\ {} \\
3u^2\,du & = (6x^2-2)\, dx
\end{align} $$ However, this doesn't give any simple thing that looks like this: $$ dx = \cdots.$$

Comment: @Piquito : Maybe if you can prove your assertion in a way that's comprehensible to those who know only elementary means of antidifferentiation, you could post it as an answer.

Comment: Are you sure about the expression ? With $2x^3-3x+1$ instead, it is integrable.

Comment: @Michael Hardy.-I would prefer that someone else do what you ask. My English is very poor and this requires a lot of discursive explanation.

Comment: @zwim.- 

If you "accommodate" the magnitudes at stake, then you can integrate, of course. But in general there is a great truth: the functions that can be integrated in closed form are VERY FEW EXCEPTIONS of a general rule involving an unnumbered number of non-integrable functions in that closed form.

Comment: This question was in a calculus exam, a friend asked me if I could help and after a few tries I thought that maybe there was a typing error.
I checked and yes, that is the same integral.